# Black-Karasinski & Market Price of Risk

Tags: interest-rates, pricing, short-rate

I have implemented the Black-Karasinski model using trinomial trees and calibrated following [Brigo (2007)](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=436070084067083008121080023070126098100075028006087054119099103100086067077083088022097027039000046111005101108124116092107072042057047080049025099110077077070066005016083005014084127027067124126001075095113090064073099011067109084074123078093072085&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE) page 29. However, the results do not fit the interest rate curve practiced in the market. As I could verify, there are something around 30 to 60bps of difference in the 10Y tenor.

Is this due to the fact that I have not used the "market price of risk" to correct my drift in the calibration? In the way I am implementing, both drift and volatility are constant for the whole simulation.

Edit1: moreover, if I analyse the outcome of these "non-adjusted by the mpr" simulations, is my analysis useless?

Thanks.

Comment: Pls add more details to your question so that it can still be understood and answered even if the link you have provided is broken or changed.

Comment: Hi what are you trying to achieve ? No model can be expected to exactly fit the market.  The market can be anywhere due to supply and demand.

Comment: The idea is to achieve a curve that fits the curve observed from the market. My question is that if I don't use the market price of risk to adjust my drift, considering that BK is a non-arbitrage model, is my analysis useless or is there any huge flaw in it?